# Double integration help?

Tags: integration

I have a question where I need to double integrate over the domain D.

The domain D is bounded in the first quadrant by the following lines:
$$x=0$$
$$y=x$$
$$x^2+y^2=1/4$$

What would the domain of integration be and how do I sketch it, Im confused so much by this. The integration part will be simple its just the domain is confusing. I assume I will get limits of integration from this domain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polar transformation:

$$\begin{cases}
x = r\cos(\theta) \\
y = r\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}.
$$

Notice that, since $ x \geq 0$ (due to boundary $x = 0$) and $x \leq y$ (due to boundary $y \leq x$), then:

$$\begin{cases}
r \in [0, 1] \\
\theta \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{4}\right]
\end{cases}.
$$

Recall that $dxdy = rdrd\theta$. Then:

$$\int\int_{D} f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(r, \theta)rd\theta dr $$

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The domain is the area bounded by the green line, the blue line and the y axis. The green line is $y=x$ and the blue line is $x^2+y^2=1/4$.

It depends on what you are integrating, but probably integrating wrt to y first is easier. The lower bound is then the line $y=x$ and the upper bound is $y=\sqrt{1/4-x^2}$. Then $x$ just goes from $0$ to the point where these two lines intersect, i.e. the positive solution to 
$$x=\sqrt{1/4-x^2}$$
which is $x=1/(2\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: The region of integration should be bounded by the y-axis, not the x-axis.

Comment: @Susan would it matter if I integrate with dy first then dx, would these limits here change or can i keep them the same?

Comment: Ethan, Oops, I've fixed it.

Comment: If you integrate with respect to different variables, the bounds change. When you integrate with respect to $x$, the lower bound is the $y$ axis, and the upper bound either the green line or blue line depending on what $y$ is (specifically, you are integrating from $\int_0^{\min(y, \sqrt{1/4-y^2})}dx)$. This can be broken up into two cases (by integrating y from 0 to $1/(2\sqrt{2})$ and and $1/(2\sqrt{2})$ to $1/2$) in order to get rid of the min. It may also be easier to convert to polar coordinates, as the_candyman suggests in the other answer, it all depends on the problem.

Comment: @Susan thankyou for your help, the polar coordinates is alot easier for me to understand